# kendo numeric text box ng model binding creating a never ending loop

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

i am trying to modify the value of the numeric text box but while updating it creates a never ending loop. the model binding should update only once

Component below

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<kendo-numerictextbox
            [spinners]="showButtons"
                          [restrictDecimals]="true"
                          [round]="false"
                          [decimals]="decimals"
                          [format]="c2"
                          [ngModel]="value"
                          (ngModelChange)="onValueChange($event)"></kendo-numerictextbox>  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public showButtons: boolean = false;
    public format: string;
    public decimals: number = 2;
    public value: number = 0;
    onValueChange(value: string) {
        this.value = value + ' USD';
        alert(value);
    }
}
```

attached plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/kjl7e1wrFJGmpKa008cT

Answer (score 0):

Note that the component works with digits only and the value that you are passing is invalid.

Comment: try with numbers like this.value = value + 5; in the given example and you will get the same result

Comment: looks like a bug. You can submit it here https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular